# javascript escape double quote in eval

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eval

I have a link button in gridview like below

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("Edit(\"{0}\", \"{1}\");return false;",Eval("Comment").ToString(),Eval("Status")) %>' >Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```

It works fine except there are double quote in comment. I tried change it to Eval("Comment").ToString().Replace(/'/g, "\'")
but got error like " The server tag is not well formed."

Any suggestion please

Comment: not many people are willing to touch eval...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Replace` you tried is trying to use Javascript.  Because the embedded quotes have already made it to the html page, Javascript no longer treats this as an entire string.  Use the .NET version of `Replace` to encode the data server-side:

VB example:

```
Eval("Comment").ToString().Replace("""", "\""")
```

This will replace all quotes in the comment with escaped quotes, meaning they won't close or start a new string unexpectedly.